# Schedule a task

Tags: java, jboss, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

Iam using jboss5.1.x, EJB3.0

I need to schedule a task in my application.
which way would you recommend me to do it according to version I am using below?

I heard about SAR, but i am not sure if there is a way which is more appropriate or updated  to do it nowdays

thanks,

ray.

Comment: For a clustered environment ,go for Quartz.

Comment: http://mhashem.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/java-quartz-scheduler-ejb-3-0-timer-service-and-java-timer-task-when-to-use-each/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [***Quartz***](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)

> Quartz is a full-featured, open source job scheduling service that can be integrated with, or used along side virtually any Java EE or Java SE application - from the smallest stand-alone application to the largest e-commerce system. Quartz can be used to create simple or complex schedules for executing tens, hundreds, or even tens-of-thousands of jobs; jobs whose tasks are defined as standard Java components that may execute virtually anything you may program them to do. The Quartz Scheduler includes many enterprise-class features, such as JTA transactions and clustering.

- [Quick Start Guide](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/quick_start_guide.html)

Comment: Do you know if Quartz will integrate with Jboss without any probs?

Comment: Quartz can be used with code java , spring also supports configurational integration, I don't see any issue with JBOSS

Comment: sure. just go through *quick guard*

Comment: Just that you know, ive just found out that JBossAS comes bundled with Quartz

Comment: But old version;P so you better replace it. anyway, how would you add it as a service to jbosS? at jboss-service.xml ? any example how to do it? thanks.

Comment: are you looking for [this](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowtoconfigureaQuartzservice)

Comment: Honest question: is there a reason to use Quartz instead of the Timer capabilities of EJB 3.1?

Comment: @partenon I haven't used EJB's timer you have mentioned. I have used Quartz it is very easy to use , easily configurable and full of feature set.

Comment: How would you configure Quartz so when then server is deployed, to start a specific bean which I have configured?

Comment: that can be another question. I have no idea for now, but other people can answer it if you post it as fresh new question.

Answer (score 1):

Java EE API javax.ejb.**TimedObject** supports the feature.

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend using Quartz. In case you cannot use it, don't forget the EJB 3.0 standard has the concept of EJB Timer services. You can read more [here](http://codeidol.com/java/netbeans/Timer-Service/Timer-Service-API/).

Answer (score 0):

In Java you have `TimerTask` , you can schedule a  task to run at the particular time.But i would recommend `Quartz`.According to your scenario , you have built in EJB Timer class available , hope  will solve the purpose.

**Please read this article**

http://mhashem.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/java-quartz-scheduler-ejb-3-0-timer-service-and-java-timer-task-when-to-use-each/